# What is the best alternative for Sleep()

Tags: delphi-2010

Im making an app using delphi and here is my code snippit

```
pnlMenu1.Visible := True;
Sleep(5000);
pnlMenu1.Visible := False;
pnlMenu2.Visible := True;
```

I need the user to still be able to do stuff while the Sleep() is running, but Sleep() stops the main thread which stops the program. Is there anything that i can replace the Sleep() with that will work? Like:

```
pnlMenu1.Visible := True;
//Wait 5 seconds but dont holt main thread
pnlMenu1.Visible := False;
pnlMenu2.Visible := True;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a TTimer. Enable the time after having made pnlMenu visible and from the OnTimer event, put the rest of your processing.

You can use a "waiting loop" wich calls ProcessMessages, but this has plenty of difficulties (Re-entering events) so be careful testing your application when user clicks everywhere.

Comment: In Delphi 10.2 and later, you can use ‘TThread.ForceQueue()’ with its ‘ADelay’ parameter to accomplish the same thing without using a timer.

Answer (score -1):

I have found a solution. For anyone with same problem :

Add this somewhere in the code:

```
procedure Delay(dwMilliseconds: Longint);
var
iStart, iStop: DWORD;
begin
iStart := GetTickCount;
repeat
iStop := GetTickCount;
Application.ProcessMessages;
Sleep(1);
until (iStop - iStart) >= dwMilliseconds;
end;
```

Then replace 'Sleep(time)' With 'Delay(time)'

So:

```
Sleep(5000);
```

is replaced with

```
Delay(5000);
```

Comment: What happens when you get some re-entrancy?